# XCode 5.1.1 crashing on right click

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I am using XCode 5.1.1 and Right click on code line is not working. It is usually crashed
And quit the xcode unexpectedly.
Please see the attached Image for the reference...

[image]

Please tell me how to fix it..

Comment: Update it to current stable version XCode 6.1 from App Store.

Comment: As @pawan told you, use 6.1.1 from the App Store, at least if you want to stick to 5, go with the latest 5.1.1 from here
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1/xcode_5.1.1.dmg

Comment: And no error message is displayed what it quits?  Does the dialog box pops asking you to submit crash info to Apple shows up?  Which version of Mac OS X are you using?

Comment: Yes pop-up box is appearing.... And I am using Mac OS X version 10.8.4.

Comment: Did this version of Xcode ever work for you?  Does the problem happen if you start a new project?  If you create a new user account on your Mac and log into that, does Xcode still fail?

Comment: Yes this version is working for me but the only problem is "Right click on code line".